# How to create an MP3 copy of FLAC collection, down to directory structure?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, mp3

I have a collection of FLAC rips that I use for archival purposes and playing on my Hi-Fi system. However, I would like to create an MP3 copy of my entire FLAC collection (for using on my laptop, phone, etc.) that imitates the directory structure, like the following:

```
 Music
      Jazz
           Miles Davis
                Kind of Blue
                     ... .mp3
                     cover.jpg
```

This way, my collection can be navigated the same way as my FLAC collection. I don't want to create the MP3s with the FLAC files. How can I do this in bash?

Using: Bash, ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following with `find`, just making sure you're putting the output outside of the target directory.

```
find ./ -type d -exec mkdir -p "../test/{}" \;
find ./ -type f -iname '*.flac' -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" "../output/{}.mp3" \;
find ./ -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec cp "{}" "../output/{}" \;
```

To rename your files to the correct extension:

```
find . -name "*.flac.mp3" -exec bash -c 'echo mv $0 ${0/.flac.mp3/.mp3}' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [mp3fs](http://khenriks.github.io/mp3fs/):

> mp3fs is a read-only FUSE filesystem which transcodes between audio
>   formats (currently FLAC to MP3) on the fly when files are opened and
>   read.
>
> It can let you use a FLAC collection with software and/or hardware
>   which only understands the MP3 format, or transcode files through
>   simple drag-and-drop in a file browser.
>
> As far as your programs are concerned, they are just regular files.

Mount your music:

```
$ mp3fs -b 192 /mnt/music /mnt/mp3 -o allow_other,ro
```

or use the following entry in `/etc/fstab`:

```
mp3fs#/mnt/music /mnt/mp3 fuse allow_other,ro,bitrate=192 0 0
```

They'll show up as MP3 files on the mountpoint mirroring the directory structure of the FLACs:

```
$ ls -l /mnt/mp3/Machinarium
total 81030
-rw-r--r-- 1 khenriks khenriks  8607397 Feb 14  2012 1-01 The Bottom.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 khenriks khenriks  6295871 Feb 14  2012 1-02 The Sea.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 khenriks khenriks  6287732 Feb 14  2012 1-03 Clockwise Operetta.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 khenriks khenriks  5157984 Feb 14  2012 1-04 Nanorobot Tune.mp3
...
```

For more info see the [manpage](http://khenriks.github.io/mp3fs/mp3fs.1.html) and [README](https://github.com/khenriks/mp3fs/blob/master/README.md).